# Instaliing opencv4tegra on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cuda

I am trying to install opencv4tegra on my host computer, which runs ubuntu 12.04, so I can cross compile with my jetson TK1. I have set up everything needed for the cross compilation and run some cuda examples, and now I need openCV for my projects.
When I downloaded and tried to install the development and runtime packages from Nvidia,
I kept getting dependency problems. I checked out my software center, and the only package I seem to miss is libtiff5- I have libtiff4. I looked it up, and as far as I can understand, there is no libtiff5 for ubuntu 12.04.
My question is- is there anyway I can install opencv4tegra on an ubuntu 12.04 machine? Or do I need to switch up to 14.04, and get libtiff5?
Thanks in advance :)

edit- forgot to mention, I also looked into downloading openCV source code, and compiling it so it would work with cuda and the gpu. Is this a solution? If so, how do I get it to work with cuda and gpu?

Comment: just curious, did the debian package for opencv4tegra disappear?  the cuda package is on their support page, but they say the opencv is coming soon i.e. there is probably some problem with it (?)

Comment: yes, they took down the download from their site, I guess because a new version is coming out (for cuda 6.5?)

Comment: Thanks.  That's too bad. Is it working for you?  Any chance you can post it somewhere?  I might end up trying to compile on the Jetson itself -overnight or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try the steps from [jetsonhacks](http://jetsonhacks.com/2014/11/26/nvidia-jetson-tk1-install-opencv-l4t-21-1/):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Get and install OpenCV for Tegra
# Linux for Tegra (LT4) 21.1 and CUDA 6.5 *must* be installed on the Jetson before installation!
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/embedded/OpenCV/L4T_21.1/libopencv4tegra-repo_l4t-r21_2.4.10.1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libopencv4tegra-repo_l4t-r21_2.4.10.1_armhf.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libopencv4tegra libopencv4tegra-dev
```